# RD Gateway 2008 R2 connection issue

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, gateway

When a user attempts to connect to their computer from a remote client using RD Gateway the connection fails if their active directory account specifically limits them to their computer but allows them to connect if they are not restricted to logging in to their own computer.

In active directory, the users' properties, Account tab, Log On To... button.
If it says "This user can log on to: All computers" it works (assuming other creds such as password and certificate of course).
If it says "This user can log on to: The following computers" (and their computer is listed) then they get "The logon attempt failed"

I have also added the gateway machine to the list of computers the user can log on to with no change. The only way I can get remote users (from outside the lan) to connect to their computer is if they are allowed to connect to all computers with no restrictions. 
Note: This only applies to external users coming in through the RD Gateway service. The "This user can log on to : All computers / The following computers works for controlling logons for users on the lan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on another forum posted a link where a microsoft tech explains you cannot use Log On To.. with rd gateway. So that's that. Unless Microsoft fixes it, that's how it is. In case anyone else is interested, here is the link.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2010/02/18/remote-desktop-gateway-and-active-directory-user-profiles.aspx